# PDF links doesn't appears in android WebView API below 19

Tags: android, pdf, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I am trying to load a URL in WebView having .pdf link.
Link is not appearing on JELLY_BEAN devices [Tested on 4.1, 4.1.1 & 4.2]
However, the link is visible on all KITKAT and above devices.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.directory_browser);
    webView = (ExtendedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webBrowser); 
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.browserProgressBar);
    progressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.browserProgressText);
    preparewebView();
    webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("medicalUrl"));

}

private void preparewebView() {
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.setInitialScale(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medical_webview_initialScale));
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //Decide whether to set a download listener
            String prefix = com.theteamie.android.uwc.Webservice.URL.getUwcseaWebappDownloadUrl();
            if (!url.startsWith(prefix)){
                Log.v("WebViewClient", "Appending downloader");
                view.setDownloadListener(new Downloader());
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different
            // scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we
            // reach 100%
            try {
                String progressText = getResources().getString(R.string.loading) + "... ";
                if (progress != 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    progressTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    progressTextView.setText(progressText + Integer.toString(progress));
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    progressTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions what could be the reason why the link is not visible in WebView for those devices.
Thanks

Comment: Did find answer, I face same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find the solution.So had to redirect to web browser only  to make it work.

Comment: ok. I use MuPDF for below Kitkat and Webview PDF.js for Kitkat and above. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Oh great.Will check them out.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**try this way may this help you**

```
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
  String pdf = "YourLink.pdf";
  webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :-

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
                }
            });
              webview.loadUrl(your_url);
```